# Adding array from async function into leaflet react not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, leaflet, react-leaflet

I currently have an asynchornous function that fetches from https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter? and prints exactly what I need:

```
async function callRelation(id) {
    const api = await fetch("https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: "[out:json];rel(" + id + ");(._;>;);out;",
    });

    const request = await api.json();

    let path = [];
    for (let pair of request.elements) {
        if (pair.type === "node") {
            path.push([pair.lat, pair.lon]);
        }
    }

    return path;
}

async function retreive() {
    let test1 = await callRelation(10000); //exmaple relationid btw
    console.log(test1);
    return test1;
}
```

It outputs a set of coordinates using an array of `[.lat,.lon]`. I'm trying to utilise `<Polyline>` but unusually it's not showing anything on the leaflet:

```
export default function Map() {
    return (
        <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
            <TileLayer
                href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Polyline pathOptions={limeOptions} positions={test} />
        </MapContainer>
    );
}
```

My previous attempts used to break leaflet because the async array would output with `undefined` in the console, but i've fixed it now which means it's another issue. However, Polyline is not outputting anything, and it works when I enter a simple test constant like:

```
const test = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 1],
];
```

How can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not show how you populate the `test` variable that is supposed to contain the array of coordinate pairs.

There is a high chance you populate it from outside your `Map` React function component, which would be the cause of React not re-rendering once you receive your asynchronous result, because React would not be aware of that change.

The solution is to have `test` as a *state* (with [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook), then to perform the async result assignment within the component function body, typically through [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook:

```
export default function Map() {
    // test placeholder as a React state
    const [test, setTest] = React.useState([]);

    // Call data fetch once on component creation
    React.useEffect(() => {
        retreive().then((test1) => {
            // When data is received, assign it to the state,
            // so that React is aware of the change
            // and re-renders the component with updated data
            setTest(test1);
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
            <TileLayer
                href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Polyline pathOptions={limeOptions} positions={test} />
        </MapContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Works as intended